# An error occurred while running npm i (exit code 1)

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I installed `Cordova` and `Ionic` on my machine, afterwards created a blank test application by typing `ionic start demo blank` however I got an error and couldn't handle it.

The result shown is like this:

```
ng directory .\demo - done!
    ading and extracting blank starter - done!
    > node-sass@4.5.3 install C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic Projects\demo\node_modules\node-sass
    > node scripts/install.jsr new app with Cordova to target native iOS and Android? Yes

    Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/win32-x64-59_binding.node
    Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.3/win32-x64-59_binding.node":

    HTTP error 404 Not Found

    Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
           try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.
    NIC  DEVAPP  *
           export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234
    p development with the Ionic DevApp, our fast, on-device testing mobile app
    or configure npm proxy via
    Test on iOS and Android without Native SDKs
           npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

    > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic
    Projects\demo\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
    > node lib/post_install.js


    > node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic Projects\demo\node_modules\node-sass
    > node scripts/build.js

    Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic
    Projects\demo\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags=
    --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
    gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\msi-nb\\Documents\\Ionic Projects\\demo\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
    gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
    gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
    gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
    gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
    gyp info using node@9.2.0 | win32 | x64
    gyp verb command rebuild []
    gyp verb command clean []
    gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
    gyp verb command configure []
    gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
    gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
    gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic
    Projects\demo\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic
    Projects\demo\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic
    Projects\demo\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic Projects\demo\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic Projects\demo\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic Projects\demo\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
    gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
    gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic
    Projects\demo\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic
    Projects\demo\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic
    Projects\demo\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic Projects\demo\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic Projects\demo\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic Projects\demo\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
    gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError
    (C:\\Users\\msi-nb\\Documents\\Ionic Projects\\demo\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F
    (C:\\Users\\msi-nb\\Documents\\Ionic Projects\\demo\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E
    (C:\\Users\\msi-nb\\Documents\\Ionic Projects\\demo\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at
    C:\\Users\\msi-nb\\Documents\\Ionic Projects\\demo\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at
    C:\\Users\\msi-nb\\Documents\\Ionic Projects\\demo\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at
    C:\\Users\\msi-nb\\Documents\\Ionic Projects\\demo\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at
    FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)',
    gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
    gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
    gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
    gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic
    Projects\demo\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic
    Projects\demo\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic
    Projects\demo\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic Projects\demo\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic Projects\demo\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic Projects\demo\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
    gyp verb `which` failed  python { Error: not found: python
    gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic
    Projects\demo\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic
    Projects\demo\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic
    Projects\demo\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic Projects\demo\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic Projects\demo\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic Projects\demo\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
    gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
    gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python\n    at getNotFoundError
    (C:\\Users\\msi-nb\\Documents\\Ionic Projects\\demo\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F
    (C:\\Users\\msi-nb\\Documents\\Ionic Projects\\demo\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E
    (C:\\Users\\msi-nb\\Documents\\Ionic Projects\\demo\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at
    C:\\Users\\msi-nb\\Documents\\Ionic Projects\\demo\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at
    C:\\Users\\msi-nb\\Documents\\Ionic Projects\\demo\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at
    C:\\Users\\msi-nb\\Documents\\Ionic Projects\\demo\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at
    FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)',
    gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
    gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
    gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
    gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
    gyp ERR! configure error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
    gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic
    Projects\demo\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
    gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic
    Projects\demo\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
    gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic Projects\demo\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
    gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:166:21)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\msi-nb\\Documents\\Ionic
    Projects\\demo\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext="
    "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic Projects\demo\node_modules\node-sass
    gyp ERR! node -v v9.2.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
    gyp ERR! not ok
    Build failed with error code: 1
    npm WARN Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic
    Projects\demo\node_modules\cryptiles\node_modules'
    npm WARN  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\msi-nb\Documents\Ionic
    Projects\demo\node_modules\cryptiles\node_modules'
    npm WARN   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir \'C:\\Users\\msi-nb\\Documents\\Ionic
    Projects\\demo\\node_modules\\cryptiles\\node_modules\'',
    npm WARN   errno: -4048,
    npm WARN   code: 'EPERM',
    npm WARN   syscall: 'scandir',
    npm WARN   path: 'C:\\Users\\msi-nb\\Documents\\Ionic Projects\\demo\\node_modules\\cryptiles\\node_modules' }
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\msi-nb\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-28T16_46_32_510Z-debug.log
```

I have seen about the same error on this link [[ERROR] An error occurred while running npm install (exit code 1):](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-an-error-occurred-while-running-npm-install-exit-code-1/90573) but I don't understand why I got this proxy error and don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Try making a ```ping github.com``` in your command console https://iihelp.iinet.net.au/How_to_run_a_ping_test

Comment: Pinging github.com [192.30.253.113] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.30.253.113: bytes=32 time=194ms TTL=49
Reply from 192.30.253.113: bytes=32 time=206ms TTL=49
Reply from 192.30.253.113: bytes=32 time=206ms TTL=49
Reply from 192.30.253.113: bytes=32 time=194ms TTL=49

Ping statistics for 192.30.253.113:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 194ms, Maximum = 206ms, Average = 200ms
@JonathanBrizio

Comment: Check that URL are returning 404 Not found! Download the lastest version of node-sass from npm https://github.com/sass/node-sass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are working behind a proxy. Either that or the node-sass repository isn't available so you download it manually:

```
npm install node-sass
```

If you sill have an error then you definitely work behind a proxy & you should configure it depending on your OS.

**Edit:**

I just run the command & everything is fine. The app runs without a problem. I think you have an issue with `nodeJs` or npm version or ionic CLI. Try downloading the latest `nodeJs` & try updating `npm` with the following command:

```
npm install npm@latest
```

My config is:

cli packages:

```
    @ionic/cli-plugin-proxy : 1.5.6
    @ionic/cli-utils        : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI)       : 3.19.0

System:

    Node : v6.11.5
    npm  : 3.10.10 
    OS   : Linux 4.4
```

Comment: I have checked my proxy settings but there is not a defined proxy setting neither automatically nor manually. I am using Win 10 and all proxy settings are off, however I am still getting the same error. I installed node-sass manually on cmd by typing npm install node-sass. It's fine and **+ node-sass@4.7.2 added 233 packages, removed 261 packages and moved 3 packages in 33.717s** but when I create a new blank ionic app, while running **npm install** command, npm is trying to install **node-sass@4.5.3** persistently and fails.

Comment: Well, in order, I've reinstalled Node.js, and checked the versions **node v9.2.0, npm v5.5.1, node-sass@4.7.2**. I have executed the command you gave "_npm install npm@latest_" **+ npm@5.5.1 updated 1 package in 20.064s** Later on, **npm install -g ionic cordova** and versions of them are **+ cordova@7.1.0, + ionic@3.19.0**. Opened my project folder and created a blank ionic app. Aand got the same error :) I couldn't understand what I am missing or what is wrong.

Comment: Check the edit I just made. Use the versions I used it's maybe an issue related to ionic CLI

Comment: Lots of thanks for your help! I have changed my node and npm versions with yours. Finally I typed **ionic serve** on cmd and Ionic application came up to my browser. You saved my days.

Comment: I think there is  some issue in ionic 4 , coz i am still having this issue