# Build job pulls repo and then starts to build the image but takes too long or ends in failure

Tags: reactjs, docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to create a simple jenkins pipeline for my react app in order to see how the concept works. Jenkins runs in a container in digitalocean and I want to be able to deploy in another container the react app. I have tested jenkins and its able to run docker commands.

I want to pull from gitlab the repo everytime the master code changes, then stop/remove the previous react container if it exists and finally build the app and deploy as a container. I also want to add that i want the docker with the react app to continue running until a new commit is made where the whole process repeats.

The build job in jenkins pull the repo and then starts to build the image but takes too long or ends in failure. I am guessing I messed up the Jenkinsfile so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Dockerfile

```
# Stage 0
# Frontend build based on Node.js
FROM node:11.15.0-alpine as build-stage
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install react-scripts@latest -g
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm run build

# Stage 1
# Production build based on Nginx with artifacts from Stage 0
FROM nginx:1.15.9-alpine
COPY config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build-stage /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 1312
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Dockerignore

```
# Items that don't need to be in a Docker image.
# Anything not used by the build system should go here.
Dockerfile
.dockerignore
.gitignore
README.md

# Artifacts that will be built during image creation.
# This should contain all files created during `npm run build`.
*/node_modules/
*/build/
```

Jenkinsfile

```
node {
   def commit_id
   stage('Preparation') {
     checkout scm
     sh "git rev-parse --short HEAD > .git/commit-id"                        
     commit_id = readFile('.git/commit-id').trim()
   }
   stage('docker stop container') {
        sh 'docker ps -f name=react-app -q | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker container stop'
        sh 'docker container ls -a -f name=react-app -q | xargs -r docker container rm'
   }
    stage('docker build') {
     sh 'docker build -t react-app .'
   }

   stage('docker run container') {
       sh 'docker run -p 1312:1312 react-app'

   }
}
```

Log

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.979MB

Step 1/14 : FROM node:11.15.0-alpine as build-stage
 ---> f18da2f58c3d
Step 2/14 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8c8351b005e4
Step 3/14 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a8e6071878e2
Step 4/14 : ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4a19ac942393
Step 5/14 : COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 112d7366e0d8
Step 6/14 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in cc9dc5a446e4
[91mnpm WARN deprecated material-ui-pickers@2.2.4: You can now upgrade to @material-ui/pickers. Documentation for v2 can be found at https://material-ui-pickers-v2.dmtr-kovalenko.now.sh/
[0m[91mnpm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.0.6: Please update: there are crash fixes
[0m[91mnpm[0m[91m WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.8 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
[0m[91mnpm[0m[91m WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.2: I wrote this module a very long time ago; you should use something else.
[0m[91mnpm[0m[91m WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
[0m
> core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /usr/src/app/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

[91m
[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Updated stack on the jenkins installation on the host machine

```
[0m[91mFATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory
[0m
<--- Last few GCs --->

[5:0x556beb570000]   119407 ms: Scavenge 229.1 (301.3) -> 218.7 (305.3) MB, 48.4 / 0.6 ms  allocation failure 
[5:0x556beb570000]   121343 ms: Scavenge 232.4 (305.3) -> 220.2 (308.3) MB, 58.7 / 0.7 ms  allocation failure 
[5:0x556beb570000]   121894 ms: Scavenge 236.4 (308.3) -> 226.9 (310.8) MB, 97.5 / 1.8 ms  allocation failure 
[5:0x556beb570000]   122169 ms: Scavenge 239.4 (310.8) -> 232.3 (315.3) MB, 189.2 / 6.8 ms  allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x1370fac25501 <JSObject>
    2: _init(aka init) [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:78] [bytecode=0x22bac55a3529 offset=363](this=0x2f4f1accd31 <PromiseArray map = 0x1c9b649e33c1>,_=0x25339ac822d1 <undefined>,resolveValueIfEmpty=-2)
    3: new constructor(aka PromiseArray) [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:24] [bytecode=0xc2a...

Resuming build at Mon Aug 05 14:43:10 UTC 2019 after Jenkins restart
Waiting to resume part of frontend-react #3: Finished waiting
Ready to run at Mon Aug 05 14:43:11 UTC 2019
[91mFATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory
[0m
<--- Last few GCs --->

[5:0x556beb570000]   119407 ms: Scavenge 229.1 (301.3) -> 218.7 (305.3) MB, 48.4 / 0.6 ms  allocation failure 
[5:0x556beb570000]   121343 ms: Scavenge 232.4 (305.3) -> 220.2 (308.3) MB, 58.7 / 0.7 ms  allocation failure 
[5:0x556beb570000]   121894 ms: Scavenge 236.4 (308.3) -> 226.9 (310.8) MB, 97.5 / 1.8 ms  allocation failure 
[5:0x556beb570000]   122169 ms: Scavenge 239.4 (310.8) -> 232.3 (315.3) MB, 189.2 / 6.8 ms  allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x1370fac25501 <JSObject>
    2: _init(aka init) [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:78] [bytecode=0x22bac55a3529 offset=363](this=0x2f4f1accd31 <PromiseArray map = 0x1c9b649e33c1>,_=0x25339ac822d1 <undefined>,resolveValueIfEmpty=-2)
    3: new constructor(aka PromiseArray) [/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:24] [bytecode=0xc2a...

[91mAborted (core dumped)
[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 134
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 134
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: provide please log from jenkins job

Comment: More than one `FROM` in one Dockerfile is a bug in Docker and should not be relied on.

Comment: I thought that was the new multistage format of dockerfile that was encouraged. No?

Comment: #alex karshin, multiple FROM is one of the latest techniques in docker, called multistage.  @Gian, in order to validate if Jenkins is the problem,  could you build your image without Jenkins? How is your Jenkins able to run perform docker orders to another container if Jenkins is inside another container or are you using dockerd rest api? I think this is the error. Could you try in an Jenkins classic installation instead of Jenkins in a container? Also, if and only if the timeout is in **NPM install**, could be a temporary networks issues.

Comment: I did build the docker locally and manually and it was able to containerize properly and then docker run it. I had followed a tutorial that addressed that problem when running jenkins inside a container so that jenkins can access docker on the host and it seemed to be working. Now I am trying an installation of jenkins on the host but again it crashed on the same step. Is the jenkinsfile correct? I mean it should be working right?

Comment: I got some extra stack trace  on the host machine that points to memory.

Comment: i think the problem is the way npm install works. I read that it doesnt free memory until its done with all the dependencies. And the host machine has 1gb ram only.

Answer (score 1):

"**[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1**" Indicates the `npm install` command failed. A quick search and I found this [An error occurred while running npm i (exit code 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47537309/an-error-occurred-while-running-npm-i-exit-code-1). I am no NPM / Node expert but between exit 1 one and that resource it reads as NPM is unable to make a connection to the remote resource. IE network / proxy issues. Can you boild the project locally (on your development machine)? Are you and the Jenkins machine on the same network / using the same access point?

Comment: I built the react app as a docker fine locally, now I am trying with jenkins on a vm in digitalocean

Comment: Ok, that is good. So we know the commands are correct. I would check that the VM has inbound 443 and outbound 1024->64000 ports open and available. As a test, I would log into the VM and run the exact commands Jenkins would run, but from a user account.

Comment: I cant check now but from what I remember all outbound ports are open and none inbound. I changed the node version to 12 and installed npm-install-que and used that to install the dep. It installs one by one the deps so its not so memory tasking. I was able to complete the installation of the deps but It crashed during the build. Probably memory again... dont know

Comment: Do you have access to the error / output logs? That is where I would start looking.

Comment: I logged in today and started Jenkins and it resumed the build process and finish it. Now its running and the app works! I guess the problem is the low specs of the machine maybe?? Another question the job now seems to be active indefinetly as I just say run the container and it does just that. Is that normal if you want to achieve what i want? Or is there a better way? Thanks a lot for your input!

Comment: Now it fails at the build stage again fro memory... It uses the cache for the dependencies so it goes straight to the build stage but again crashes.

Comment: Sounds like not a Docker problem as this point; more a host resource problem. Double the host resources and see if you still get the out of MEM error. I have also run into problems if the build instance is to small / not having swap memory enabled.

Comment: I think so too. I moved to Gitlab CI which builds the project on their own servers and then pulls the docker image to deploy in the droplet. Seems to be working fine so far ... Thanks a lot David!